# Manifest merger failed after i included compile 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.1' dependency

Tags: android

gradle failing to sync after I include either of these dependencies :

```
compile 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.1'
compile 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.5'
```

I have added the code to the the project level build.gradle file

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

my sdk version and build versions are:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
```

The error message shown:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than 
version 16 declared in library [com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.1] 
C:\Users\AMAR\.android\build-
cache\1bfbeadb45d10ea7837f57f92c0748e4a7540c09\output\AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.mancj.materialsearchbar" to force 
usage
```

Comment: make minSdkVersion 16 in your build.gradle

Comment: Add  in your AndroidManifest.xml ->  <application tools:overrideLibrary="com.mancj.materialsearchbar"> </application>
I hope i will help you.

Comment: @Nikunj Thanks bro, I cant believe it was that simple, the application works just fine but the gradle build was slower than usual, will this(changing minSdkVersion) be any problem if I add any dependencies in the future?

Comment: no, changing minSdkVersion to upper level won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add below `uses-sdk` tag in your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest >
......
    <uses-sdk  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:overrideLibrary="com.mancj.materialsearchbar"
    android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
......
</manifest>
```

It is already suggested in the error message:

```
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.mancj.materialsearchbar" to force
```

usage

This will override the manifest merger process and use min SDK as 15.
I hope this will help you.